# Wrapping a string dynamically in WordPress with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

## Question

How can I replace a ® symbol to `<sup>&reg;</sup>` . More specifically what is the cleanest way to do it in a WordPress project?

### Background

I had a Javascript solution that worked in my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/bgxgqq).

But I want this to happen on the server, not clientside. Where is the best standard place to put this in a WP project? I am only tasked with maintaining a theme, so putting it in there, but where exactly?

Also, the code was only replacing the first ®. So I need to loop that.

---

### Code

#### Javascript

```
function regReplace() {
    var regStr = document.getElementById("target-div").innerHTML; 
    var resSup = regStr.replace("®", "<sup>&reg;</sup>");
    document.getElementById("target-div").innerHTML = resSup;
}
regReplace();
```

Comment: change it in: theme html? user added content? hard coded php?

Comment: `str_replace("®", "<sup>&rep;</sup>", $string);` ? Unless you're receiving it differently within the PHP?

Comment: @nogad I hardcoded where I could but some of the user added content is what is causing the problem.

Comment: @Darren i'm sure you are right. Just not sure where to put that. I have one page that serves as a template for these pages I am working on. Threw your code in between `<?php  [added code here] ?>` and put it at the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to [use a filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) to [hook into the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/). All you need for it to work is a filter function that replaces your substring with another one.

#### Site-wide replace

This replaces all occurrences of ® with your desired HTML in all user generated content.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_stuff');

function replace_stuff($content) {
    return str_replace("®", "<sup>&rep;</sup>", $content);
}
```

#### Replace only on a specific page

This replaces all occurrences only on the page matched by the slug specified here as `'your-slug'`.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'maybe_replace_stuff');

function maybe_replace_stuff($content) {

    $post = get_post();
    $slug = $post->post_name;

    if ($slug === 'your-slug') {
        $content = str_replace("®", "<sup>&rep;</sup>", $content);
    }

    return $content;
}
```

#### Replace only on a set of specific pages

Pretty much the same as above, except with multiple page slugs to check against.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'maybe_replace_stuff');

function maybe_replace_stuff($content) {

    $acceptedSlugs = array('foo', 'bar');

    $post = get_post();
    $slug = $post->post_name;

    if (in_array($slug, $acceptedSlugs)) {
        $content = str_replace("®", "<sup>&rep;</sup>", $content);
    }

    return $content;
}
```

#### Replace only if a specific template is used for the post

```
add_filter('the_content', 'maybe_replace_stuff');

function maybe_replace_stuff($content) {

    $post = get_post();
    $template = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);

    if ($template === 'your-template.php') {
        $content = str_replace("®", "<sup>&rep;</sup>", $content);
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: could I add it in the template (for these pages) at the top? This is not working for me, I imagine because I am not adding it correctly.

Comment: `the_content` filter is for the postbox content only. Not for sidebar, menus and widgets. So it doesn't look like it'll work that way.

Comment: Well obviously, to replace the occurrences in your template files, just do a project-wide search in your favorite text editor and be done with it. The snippet above should be added to your functions.php file to work across the entire site.

Comment: @ppajer that was not the question at all. I mean that the page is a template that I uploaded to WP, that template is used on 10 different items, and that is managed in the CMS. Since the content is added in the CMS, that is why I am asking about how to manage just that one template page that gets reused.

Comment: @JGallardo Sorry, the first part of my comment was a reply to Nirjhar suggesting this doesn't work in places not managed by the CMS - I sometimes forget to tag people on a touchscreen. :) So you don't need to replace the strings in *all* the posts, just specific categories? If so I'll have to modify my answer.

Comment: @ppajer not even categories. there is only one page that will have text on it that will be coming from the server. and since i cannot hard code someone's text later, i have to target only this page. I cannot make it global.

Comment: @JGallardo That can be solved with a conditional check against the slug of the current page. Updating my answer.

Comment: @JGallardo Updated. Let me know if this doesn't work for your case :)

Comment: @ppajer wondering I think there can be an even more simplified way of doing this because in your proposed solution, you have to enter an array of slugs, and this is done manually. But in the project they will be added dynamically. I think if I add this script only to this page, we don't need to factor in the slug. thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work, never actually experimented with adding filters inside the templates as WP always states to put them in `functions.php`. Might still work. - Another idea would be to check if the current page is using a specific template inside the function, and apply the filter only then. I think this is the correct solution if you want it to be slug-agnostic but template-aware. Added to the answer :)